# Where is the cached data with HTML5 manifest for iOS

Tags: ios, html, manifest, offline-mode

In the post H[TML5 offline webapps: a practical example](http://blog.cubeanywhere.com/2010/10/html5-offline-webapps-practical-example.html) we knew that there are 3 different storage of cached files.

My question is:

Where is the cached files with manifest in iOS app ?

I used iPhone Explorer to find such files by searching all directories, but can not find any.

Comment: I think cache files are not stored as individual files but as a chunk in some DB file.

Comment: yes,ApplicationCache.db ( sort of ). Can use sqlite3 to open for query. Any one has real experience for this ?